# How do I get the databases that are currently being backed up

Tags: sql-server

I need a list of databases that are currently being backed up and store them into a object variable in c#. Tried to query `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests
where command like 'BACKUP%'`, and it did not return anything. Then I checked `sp_whoisactive`, and it is showing that the target db backup process is `Suspended`.

So here come the question:

1. Is that because the db backup is suspended, it did not show in the result from the 1st query?
2. How can I get the table list from `sp_whoisactive` where the `sql_text` has xml like `<?query - BACKUP DATABASE...`?

Comment: The `LIKE` wildcard is `%`, not `*`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ty Jeroen, typo here.

Comment: Are the backups built from a sql job? If so, check stop_execution_date from sysJobActivity...

Comment: That's OK, but if that typo was also present when you were checking for `BACKUP` commands it would explain things, no? `LIKE '%BACKUP%'` really should be returning the backup commands; `sp_whoisactive` does not have  a magical window into requests as yet unseen -- that I know of.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, since the log and db backup will always start with `BACKUP`, I skipped the first `%`. Yes, my point is how to store the result from `sp_whoisactive`, or what is the actual query behind that..